# Unable to consecutively launch a new chrome session

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to open a website, close the browser session, and open the website on a new window. But I get an error after the first browser session is closed.

Browser: Chrome

Browser Version: 81.0.4044.138

Chrome Driver Version: 81.0.4044.138

Here is my code

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/n/Downloads/chromedriver')

driver.get('https://stackoverflow.com/')
driver.maximize_window()

driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/header/div/ol[2]/li[2]/a[1]').click()
time.sleep(5)

driver.quit()


driver.get('https://stackoverflow.com/')
driver.maximize_window()
```

Here is the error I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/n/PycharmProjects/Selenium/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 160, in _new_conn
    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw
  File "/Users/n/PycharmProjects/Selenium/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 84, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/Users/n/PycharmProjects/Selenium/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 74, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/n/PycharmProjects/Selenium/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 677, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked,
  File "/Users/n/PycharmProjects/Selenium/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 392, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1244, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1290, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1239, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 966, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/Users/n/PycharmProjects/Selenium/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 187, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/Users/n/PycharmProjects/Selenium/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 172, in _new_conn
    self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x1079f9b10>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/n/PycharmProjects/Selenium/venv/Automation/Testing/src_phase4/stack_test.py", line 15, in <module>
    driver.get('https://stackoverflow.com/')
  File "/Users/n/PycharmProjects/Selenium/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 333, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "/Users/n/PycharmProjects/Selenium/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 319, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
  File "/Users/n/PycharmProjects/Selenium/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 374, in execute
    return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
  File "/Users/n/PycharmProjects/Selenium/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 397, in _request
    resp = self._conn.request(method, url, body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/Users/n/PycharmProjects/Selenium/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/request.py", line 80, in request
    method, url, fields=fields, headers=headers, **urlopen_kw
  File "/Users/n/PycharmProjects/Selenium/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/request.py", line 171, in request_encode_body
    return self.urlopen(method, url, **extra_kw)
  File "/Users/n/PycharmProjects/Selenium/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/poolmanager.py", line 336, in urlopen
    response = conn.urlopen(method, u.request_uri, **kw)
  File "/Users/n/PycharmProjects/Selenium/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 765, in urlopen
    **response_kw
  File "/Users/n/PycharmProjects/Selenium/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 765, in urlopen
    **response_kw
  File "/Users/n/PycharmProjects/Selenium/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 765, in urlopen
    **response_kw
  File "/Users/n/PycharmProjects/Selenium/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 725, in urlopen
    method, url, error=e, _pool=self, _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]
  File "/Users/n/PycharmProjects/Selenium/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 439, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=57825): Max retries exceeded with url: /session/2808efbb67f09baa943cc4acda452537/url (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x1079f9b10>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused'))

Process finished with exit code 1
```

The problem disappears when I initialize a new driver variable and use it to open a new chrome window.

```
driver2 = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/n/Downloads/chromedriver')

driver2.get('https://stackoverflow.com/')

driver2.maximize_window()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try re-initializing the instance of the webdriver after the quit() using its **init** method. Like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/n/Downloads/chromedriver')

driver.get('https://stackoverflow.com/')
driver.maximize_window()

driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/header/div/ol[2]/li[2]/a[1]').click()
time.sleep(5)

driver.quit()

driver.__init__()


driver.get('https://stackoverflow.com/')
driver.maximize_window()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for that. Do you have any idea why this is happening in the first place?